# How to create custom border style in JavaFX CSS?

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to create border style similar to predifened "dashed" style
(`-fx-border-style: dashed`).

How to create dashed border in CSS with custom lengths of dash segments, line cap and line join?

Comment: border: 2px dashed blue; Well it's width depends on the div(or other element) for which you use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [JavaFX CSS reference for `Region`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region), in particular the possible values for `-fx-border-style`. You can use `segments(...)` to define arbitrary line segment lengths: there are also settings for `line-cap` (`square`, `butt`, or `round`) and `line-join` (`miter`, `bevel`, or `round`).

Quick example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomBorderExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Region region = new Region();
        region.getStyleClass().add("custom-dashed-border");
        region.setMinSize(400, 400);
        StackPane root = new StackPane(region);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 480, 480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("custom-dashed-border.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with

custom-dashed-border.css:

```
.custom-dashed-border {
    -fx-border-color: blue ;
    -fx-border-width: 5 ; 
    -fx-border-style: segments(10, 15, 15, 15)  line-cap round ;
}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: How I can add border to just once direction? like border-left, border-right etc?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq -fx-border-color:  transparent blue transparent  transparent

Comment: top bottom left right